# How to convert value back from "%02x" in Java?

Tags: java, type-conversion, uuid, primitive-types

I have a byte array that is converted to a string in a known way.

```
public String getValueString(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result.append(String.format("%02X", data[i]));
    }
    return result.toString;
}
```

I am looking for the way to convert String to byte array.

Actually the byte array is UUID but it is represented in a strange way and method

```
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] data)
```

doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***It is very easy and simple try:***

```
byte[] data = string.getBytes();
byte[] data = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

***To convert a byte array to UIID:***

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(inputByteArray);   
long firstLong = bb.getLong();   
long secondLong = bb.getLong();  

return new UUID(firstLong, secondLong);
```

***What about:***

```
  int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
```

`data` is your byte array.

Comment: The last one did the trick, thanks a lot, I stuck with that for few hours) Have to work less maybe))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to convert the hex numbers back to bytes:

```
String str = "4FDD3A";
byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length()/2];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    if ((i+1)*2 <= str.length()) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2, (i+1)*2), 16);
    }
}
for (byte b: bytes) {
    System.out.format("%02x\n", b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do need that in bytes instead of printing as string and formatting again.

Comment: That was just to demonstrate that the result was correct. Obviously the printing is not required.